# anchor tags an positioning

Tags: html, css

Does anyone know of a way to design your anchor tags such that when you click on an the link to your anchor tag, it takes you to a position relative to your anchor tag, when there is nothing inside your anchor tag.

For instance,

I have a link at the top of my page that goes to an anchor tag, and if I slip text in the anchor tag I can relatively position where the link goes to anywhere on the page. If I take the text out however, the anchor tag still works but I can't position where the link goes.

Short of putting the anchor on a different element is there a good way to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly you want to move to different anchors depending on some condition. You can do this with javascript.
Attach javascript function to your link's click event. Inside this function check your condition (if some div or other element is empty for example) and then set **window.location.hash** property to the anchor that you want.

Some more info:
http://www.ezineasp.net/post/Javascript-Location-Hash-with-Example.aspx

Comment: No. I want normal anchor functionality as can be achieved simply with

<a href="#name">Object</a> and 

<a name="name">Object2</a>.

But I don't want to include Object2.

Comment: Because when you use an empty anchor you can't change the position of the tag. I discovered that you can just make the fon-size: 0px; and that does the job.